# rsync: link_stat failed: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-mate, rsync

I am trying to diagnose this error. Rsync does copy reminderfox.ics sucessfully.
So why am I getting that message?  Ubuntu Mate 18.04

```
Backing up Hard Drive.
  adding: fstab (deflated 43%)
rsync: link_stat "/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/dsgt0f2o.default/reminderfox.ics" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

rm fstab
# Backup UserChrome
cd $Seamonkey_User_Chrome_Dir
zip -u UserChrome.zip userChrome.css
rsync --progress -r -u -q UserChrome.zip $Backup_Directory 
# Backup reminderfox reminders This WORKS
cd $Seamonkey_Dir
rsync --progress -r -u -q reminderfox.ics $Backup_Directory
```

Comment: What version of the OS are you running?

Comment: @ David Ubuntu Mate 18.04